# tmux/screen alternative for powershell

Tags: windows, cygwin, powershell, tmux

Is there an alternative to tmux/screen that would work on Windows with Powershell? I'm aware of Powerscreen, but it seems dead for a long time. Cygwin wouldn't work with Powershell, would it? Console2 is *very* poors man solution.

Any other thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's been a while since I've used Windows but just came across https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/features.html which would fit my requirements quite well

among other things it has tabs and vertical/horizontal splits

Comment: In that case, the new Windows Terminal would probably have fit your needs as well.  It looks to have features on par with (or ahead of, in some cases) Wez's.  Also ConEmu/Cmder, as @aztack's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1013073/1210833).  That said, with Windows Subsystem for Linux, it's really possible to use `tmux` directly with PowerShell.  I'll write up a separate answer on that.  I hadn't brought it back up since I figured you'd moved on from the question, but since you bumped it today, I'll go ahead and add it.

Answer (score 21):

Although it wasn't possible when this question was originally asked, with Windows Subsystem for Linux, it's now possible to use a "real" `tmux` to manage PowerShell windows.

#### Short-version

In a WSL instance with `tmux` installed, set up your `~/.tmux.conf` with:

```
set -g default-command "cd $(pwsh.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine \$env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath); exec pwsh.exe --nologo"
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
bind c new-window -n "PowerShell"
```

#### Benefits and Features

Most of the features you'd normally expect from `tmux`, including:

- Full (?) hotkeys support
- Scrollback / Copy mode for PowerShell
- And many more

#### Limitations

- If the original session is disconnected, re-attaching will result in a broken pipe.  However, you can attach multiple clients at once, as long as the original remains open.

#### More details

There are several ways to set this up, but here's how I'm doing it at the moment:

- Install Windows Subsystem for Linux.  You don't have to enable WSL2; just WSL v1 will work fine for this (and perhaps better than WSL2).
- Install the Alpine Linux distribution.  I use this as the base for the tmux feature, since it has very low overhead (less than 12MB, including `tmux`).
- The next few steps are optional.  I create a new, cloned WSL instance for PowerShell tmux.  You could just use the default Alpine instance, but I like to have single-purpose WSL instances, similar to Docker containers.

  ```
  mkdir $env:userprofile\Documents\WSL\instances # Or wherever you want to set this up
  mkdir $env:userprofile\Documents\WSL\images
  cd $env:userprofile\Documents\WSL
  wsl --export Alpine .\images\alpine_base.tar
  mkdir .\instances\posh_tmux
  wsl --import posh_tmux .\instances\posh_tmux .\images\alpine_base.tar --version 1
  ```
- Launch the WSL instance as root with `wsl -d posh_tmux -u root`
- `adduser tmux`, and give it a password.
- Set the default user for the instance by creating `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
  [user]
  default = tmux
  ```
- `apk add tmux` to install `tmux`
- Exit the session, relaunch with `wsl ~ -d tmux` (omitting the username, since it will now default to the tmux user)
- Create a `~/.tmux.conf` with the following:

  ```
  set -g default-command "cd $(pwsh.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine \$env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath); exec pwsh.exe --nologo"
  set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
  bind c new-window -n "PowerShell"

  # Give this tmux a "PowerShell blue" color to differentiate it
  set -g status-bg blue

  # Use UTF8
  set -qg utf8
  set-window-option -qg utf8 on

  # Recommended, to avoid the Ctrl+B finger-gymnastics
  # Change default prefix to Screen's
  unbind C-b
  set-option -g prefix C-a
  bind-key C-a send-prefix
  bind-key -n C-b send-prefix
  bind C-a last-window

  # Optional
  # split panes using - and |
  bind | split-window -h
  bind - split-window -v
  unbind '"'
  unbind %

  set -g history-limit 10000

  set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
  ```
- Create a `~/.profile` with the following:

  ```
  if tmux has-session -t=posh; then
    exec tmux attach-session -t posh
  else
    exec tmux new-session -s posh -n PowerShell
  fi
  ```
- Set up a `PowerShell Core tmux` profile in Windows Terminal, ConEmu, or however you prefer.  The launch command is simply `wsl -d tmux_posh`
- If you need to access the instance without entering tmux/PowerShell (for instance, to `sudo apk upgrade` or to edit the config), launch instead with `wsl ~ -d tmux_posh -e sh` (or `wsl ~ -d tmux_posh -u root`).
- You can access `tmux` commands from within PowerShell by `wsl -d tmux_posh -e tmux <tmux_command`.  For instance, `wsl -d tmux_posh -e tmux rename-window host1`.  TODO:  Create a `tmux` wrapper PowerShell function for this.
- TODO:  PowerShell prompt function to set the window name dynamically to the last executed command

Comment: Your walkthrough is over and above. Thank you! I feel corporate advancement pulling me back toward Windows like a black hole, and I've been anxiously scanning the horizon for something like this.

Comment: Thanks @LaTeX2enub1336.  I can understand that.  WSL gives us CLI-junkies some good alternatives in Windows.  It's sometimes fun to see just how much we can use it and abuse it.  I've come across one person here and on Reddit that has run 17 different distros (at last count) on WSL.  On a similar question/answer to this one, you might also be interested in [this tip](https://superuser.com/a/1664131/1210833) for using Linux `ls` (or `exa`, or really a lot of Linux commands) in PowerShell.

Comment: Can we have a zellij version of this?

Comment: On my setup, you need `powershell.exe` instead of `pwsh.exe`

Comment: @Alex Sorry, long delay on the response, but your question came to mind when I Googled, *"rust tmux screen alternative"* today and found Zellig.  Given that it's Rust-based, I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't have a Windows built already.  I'm sure you could get the Linux version working using similar instructions to what I provided above, but I was really hoping that my hack-around wouldn't be necessary with a Rust-based alternative.  Related - https://github.com/zellij-org/zellij/issues/3107#issuecomment-1926401975

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yeah, Zellij is now the cutting edge in session managing. The main developer however is looking for sponsership or long term funding in order to implement many time-demanding features like windows support and many other ones. I switched my life to Linux altogether but would be happy to see that materialize.

Answer (score 11):

It's not precisely analogous to tmux or screen, but PowerShell has a facility for managing remote sessions. Ed Wilson wrote a blog post about it entitled [Learn How to Manage Remote PowerShell Sessions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-how-to-manage-remote-powershell-sessions/), which might help. Also see the [about_PSSessions PowerShell help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions).

Can you say more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 10):

Try Cmder. It's awesome! It even bundled with git for windows.
https://cmder.app/

Comment: That appears to be just a terminal emulator, which is cool but that isn't what screen/tmux do.  They provide persistent sessions which you can reconnect to if you get disconnected etc so the tmux session is on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify your requirements, so it's somewhat hard to answer your post.

You could try the free [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), which can incorporate PowerShell tabs :

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features
> include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different
> background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font,
> different window styles.

For details see this article : [Console – Windows Command Prompt alternative for Windows and PowerShell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

[image]

(*Note: Remember that this answer is from 2012*.)

Answer (score 1):

I am partial to Extraterm, it has plenty of advanced functinality
it supports Powershell, wls, cmd, cwgyn, and more.

https://extraterm.org/
https://github.com/sedwards2009/extraterm/releases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the issue myself. I was not happy with the current solutions (making multiple ssh connections in a tabbed console).

So I made my own tool (similar to tmux).

https://github.com/osen/vimux

Dead simple to use, just extract and run bin/vimux. Or preferably add that bin folder to PATH to just run 'vimux'