# Show human-readable file sizes in the default PowerShell ls command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I modify the default `ls` (`Get-ChildItem`) in PowerShell so that it displays human-readable file sizes, like `ls -h` on a *nix machine?

`ls -lh` does simple logic with the file size, so that it shows bytes for really small files, kilobytes for files over 1K (with one decimal place if it's under 10K), and megabytes for files over 1M (with one decimal place if it's under 10MB).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this

```
PS> gc c:\scripts\type\shrf.ps1xml

<Types>
<Type>
  <Name>System.IO.FileInfo</Name>
   <Members>
      <ScriptProperty>
          <Name>FileSize</Name>
          <GetScriptBlock>
             switch($this.length) {
               { $_ -gt 1tb } 
                      { "{0:n2} TB" -f ($_ / 1tb) }
               { $_ -gt 1gb } 
                      { "{0:n2} GB" -f ($_ / 1gb) }
               { $_ -gt 1mb } 
                      { "{0:n2} MB " -f ($_ / 1mb) }
               { $_ -gt 1kb } 
                      { "{0:n2} KB " -f ($_ / 1Kb) }
               default  
                      { "{0} B " -f $_} 
             }      
          </GetScriptBlock>
     </ScriptProperty>   
  </Members>
</Type>
</Types>

PS> Update-TypeData -AppendPath c:\scripts\type\shrf.ps1xml -verbose
PS> get-childItem $env:windir  | select Name,FileSize,length
PS> # you can paste this in your profile
PS>
```

you can also use dynamic type data with PS3:

```
   PS> Update-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -MemberName FileSize -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value { 

    switch($this.length) {
               { $_ -gt 1tb } 
                      { "{0:n2} TB" -f ($_ / 1tb) }
               { $_ -gt 1gb } 
                      { "{0:n2} GB" -f ($_ / 1gb) }
               { $_ -gt 1mb } 
                      { "{0:n2} MB " -f ($_ / 1mb) }
               { $_ -gt 1kb } 
                      { "{0:n2} KB " -f ($_ / 1Kb) }
               default  
                      { "{0} B " -f $_} 
             }      

 } -DefaultDisplayPropertySet Mode,LastWriteTime,FileSize,Name
```

Comment: I really like building it in as an extra property. The only problem using the PS3 version is I get: `Update-TypeData : Error in TypeData "System.IO.FileInfo": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.` Running latest PS3 full release from 9/4.

Comment: Great answer!  It's hard to believe there isn't a switch for `Get-ChildItem` that would just do this out of the box

Comment: Great answer but has anyone got `-DefaultDisplayPropertySet` to work?

Comment: Doesn't work like @ThomasG.Mayfield said.

Comment: How can anyone take powershell seriously, when simple things like listing files with human readable sizes, requires writing your own scripts.

Comment: Nice answer but once again I find it hilarious how much Powershell code you have to write to accomplish something as simple as `-h`

Comment: I agree that PowerShell has much room to improve. We're so used to `-h` that we may forget that it was an extension to POSIX. The original `ls` command didn't support `-h`. You'd think that something built today would learn from the past, but that isn't always the case.

Comment: Do I really need all this lengthy script, if all I want is just thousand separator (i.e., `1,234` instead of `1234`) in `Length`, which even old DOS `dir` has), not fancy "human-readable" size like "123MB"?

Answer (score 24):

Something like the following for listing just file sizes.  Yes it is a bit sore on the eyes but it manages to get the job done.

For converting to KB:

```
ls | Select-Object Name, @{Name="KiloBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1KB}}
```

For converting to MB:

```
ls | Select-Object Name, @{Name="MegaBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}
```

Comment: To make it more readable (less sore on eye), I add some whitespace before the number with this:

`ls | Select-Object Name, @{Name="-------------MegaBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}`  You can also use spaces (dashes here for clarity).

Answer (score 21):

First, create the following function:

```
Function Format-FileSize() {
    Param ([int64]$size)
    If     ($size -gt 1TB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} TB", $size / 1TB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1GB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} GB", $size / 1GB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1MB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} MB", $size / 1MB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1KB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} kB", $size / 1KB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 0)   {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} B", $size)}
    Else                   {""}
}
```

You can then pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` through `Select-Object` and use a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to format the filesize:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Size";Expression={Format-FileSize($_.Length)}}
```

The function could of course be improved to account for sizes in the PB range and more, or to vary the number of decimal points as necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason that an alias can't be created to do this as getshilditem itself (check is there is an -lh flag or something, and if not, then just use Get-ChildItem, else use this)

Comment: You can't create aliases for piped commands, nor override the default aliases. If you can live with using an alias like `ls2`, try creating another function that does the logic you described based on a parameter, then add an alias for it. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx) for more information on creating aliases.

Comment: Alternatively, look into [custom formatting files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878272(v=vs.85).aspx) to extend cmdlet output. See [this forum topic](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/78124-extended-get-childitem-output.html) for an example. Also, to make the formatting function persist through PowerShell sessions, add it to your profile file (see `Get-Variable profile` for its location).

Comment: For me, this function doesn't work files larger than ~2GB, as `$size ` is defined as an `int`, which is [a `int32`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/). For this to work with large files, define `$size` as `int64` or `uint64`.

Comment: I get `Select-Object : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "System.Collections.Hashtable" akzeptiert.`. How can I specify the path? I use `$pst= Get-ChildItem -Path $home_user -Filter *.pst -Recurse -File| Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object{ $_.FullName}`. This works, but without file sizes.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a bit of an orthogonal answer to this quite-old question.  It's not an answer to the question *as literally asked*, but more about the "spirit" of the question.  It's also not an answer that was even possible for years after the question was asked.  But now, it may be useful for some subset of folks who come looking for this information (as I did today).

Since the original question pointed out how easy this is in *nix, I realized that with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) installed, it's a no-brainer to just use the Linux `ls -lh` from PowerShell:

```
PS> wsl ls -lh
```

... gives me the results I want (and it sounds like the OP did) on the current directory from within PowerShell.  Better yet, if you have `exa` installed in your WSL instance, `wsl exa -l` is much prettier (and defaults to `-h`).

Note that if you want a *different* directory, there's a bit of a "trick" when using the `wsl` command.  Since utilities running inside a WSL instance (such as `ls`) only understand Linux paths, you can't do something like:

```
PS> wsl ls -lh C:\
```

Instead, there are two options.  First, you can use the WSL equivalent of the Windows path.  E.g.:

```
PS> wsl ls -lh /mnt/c
PS> wsl exa -l /mnt/c
```

Or, just set the directory for the WSL instance with the `--cd` option, like so:

```
PS> wsl --cd C:\ ls -lh # or
PS> wsl --cd C:\ exa -l
```

This also works with relative directory paths:

```
PS> wsl --cd .. ls -lh # or
PS> wsl --cd .. exa -l
```

Don't worry (if you were) -- it's not going to change the current directory in PowerShell.  When the WSL instance exits after running `ls` command, PowerShell will retain its current environment; just like running a subshell (in either PowerShell or a Linux shell like Bash).

PowerShell and WSL are each great on their own, but putting the two together gives you something even more powerful.

P.S. This works with either WSL1 or WSL2, but if you are going to be handling a lot of Windows files in WSL, version 1 is (currently) an order of magnitude faster.  WSL2 is faster when using the virtualized ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Wow, II did not know you could run WSL in PowerShell. No more verbose PS BS. Thanks for this!

Comment: If this does not work, check your default sub system with `wslconfig /l`. If it is not Ubuntu the use `wslconfig /s` to change this. Then everything works. My default sub system was docker, and this was not working at all with docker.

Comment: @soulflyman True, but to be honest, this caveat applies to just about *every* answer that uses the `wsl` command ;-).  Also note that `wslconfig` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands).  The recommended replacement would be `wsl -l -v` and `wsl --set-default <distro>`.  Thanks!

Comment: Sneaky, I like it. The first function call is a little sluggish if you're starting up your `wsl` for the first time but subsequent calls are instantaneous.

Comment: @Cerberton Great point - I never really consider that since WSL is one of the first things I typically start up ;-)

Answer (score 7):

based on the answer by walid toumi:

Steps to do:

- Create your own Type-file with the new `FileSize`-Property
- Change the standard output format for FileInfo
- load the changes in `$PROFILE`

#### Create your own Type-file with the new `FileSize`-Property

- Create your own Type-file: `MyTypes.ps1xml`
  (I put it in `$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowershell`, so right next to my `$PROFILE`)

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Types>
      <Type>
          <Name>System.IO.FileInfo</Name>
          <Members>
              <ScriptProperty>
                  <!-- Filesize converts the length to a human readable
                      format (kb, mb, gb, tb) -->
                  <Name>FileSize</Name>
                  <GetScriptBlock>
                      switch($this.length) {
                          { $_ -gt 1tb } 
                              { "{0:n2} TB" -f ($_ / 1tb) ; break }
                          { $_ -gt 1gb } 
                              { "{0:n2} GB" -f ($_ / 1gb) ; break }
                          { $_ -gt 1mb } 
                              { "{0:n2} MB " -f ($_ / 1mb) ; break }
                          { $_ -gt 1kb } 
                              { "{0:n2} KB " -f ($_ / 1Kb) ; break }
                          default
                              { "{0}  B " -f $_}
                      }
                  </GetScriptBlock>
              </ScriptProperty>
          </Members>
      </Type>
  </Types>
  ```
- load the new property in a powershell-session:

  - `Update-TypeData -PrependPath $Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowershell\MyTypes.ps1xml`
- try the new property

  - `Get-ChildItem | Format-Table -Property Name, Length, FileSize`

#### Change the standard output format for FileInfo

- create your own Fileformat-file: `MyFileFormat.format.ps1xml`
  (Again in `$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowershell\`)

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <Configuration>
      <SelectionSets>
          <SelectionSet>
              <Name>FileSystemTypes</Name>
              <Types>
                  <TypeName>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</TypeName>
                  <TypeName>System.IO.FileInfo</TypeName>
              </Types>
          </SelectionSet>
      </SelectionSets>

      <!-- ################ GLOBAL CONTROL DEFINITIONS ################ -->
      <Controls>
          <Control>
              <Name>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</Name>
                      <CustomControl>
                          <CustomEntries>
                              <CustomEntry>
                                  <CustomItem>
                                      <Frame>
                                          <LeftIndent>4</LeftIndent>
                                          <CustomItem>
                                              <Text AssemblyName="System.Management.Automation" BaseName="FileSystemProviderStrings" ResourceId="DirectoryDisplayGrouping"/>
                                              <ExpressionBinding>
                                                <ScriptBlock>
                                                    $_.PSParentPath.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")                                                  
                                                </ScriptBlock>
                                              </ExpressionBinding>
                                              <NewLine/>
                                          </CustomItem> 
                                      </Frame>
                                  </CustomItem>
                              </CustomEntry>
                          </CustomEntries>
              </CustomControl>
          </Control>
      </Controls>

      <!-- ################ VIEW DEFINITIONS ################ -->

      <ViewDefinitions>
         <View>
              <Name>children</Name>
              <ViewSelectedBy>
                  <SelectionSetName>FileSystemTypes</SelectionSetName>
              </ViewSelectedBy>
              <GroupBy>
                  <PropertyName>PSParentPath</PropertyName> 
                  <CustomControlName>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</CustomControlName>  
              </GroupBy>
              <TableControl>
                  <TableHeaders>
                     <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Mode</Label>
                        <Width>7</Width>
                        <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                     </TableColumnHeader>
                      <TableColumnHeader>
                          <Label>LastWriteTime</Label>
                          <Width>25</Width>
                          <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                      </TableColumnHeader>
                      <TableColumnHeader>
                          <Label>FileSize</Label>
                          <Width>14</Width>
                          <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                      </TableColumnHeader>
                      <TableColumnHeader/>
                  </TableHeaders>
                  <TableRowEntries>
                      <TableRowEntry>
                          <Wrap/>
                          <TableColumnItems>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Mode</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <ScriptBlock>
                                      [String]::Format("{0,10}  {1,8}", $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("d"), $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("t"))
                                  </ScriptBlock>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>FileSize</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                          </TableColumnItems>
                      </TableRowEntry>
                  </TableRowEntries>
              </TableControl>
          </View>
          <View>
              <Name>children</Name>
              <ViewSelectedBy>
                  <SelectionSetName>FileSystemTypes</SelectionSetName>
              </ViewSelectedBy>
              <GroupBy>
                  <PropertyName>PSParentPath</PropertyName> 
                  <CustomControlName>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</CustomControlName>  
              </GroupBy>
              <ListControl>
                  <ListEntries>
                      <ListEntry>
                          <EntrySelectedBy>
                              <TypeName>System.IO.FileInfo</TypeName>
                          </EntrySelectedBy>
                          <ListItems>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>FileSize</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                             <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>CreationTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>LastWriteTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>LastAccessTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Mode</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>LinkType</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Target</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>                        
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>VersionInfo</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                          </ListItems>
                      </ListEntry>
                      <ListEntry>
                          <ListItems>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>CreationTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>LastWriteTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem>
                                  <PropertyName>LastAccessTime</PropertyName>
                              </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                              <PropertyName>Mode</PropertyName>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                              <PropertyName>LinkType</PropertyName>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                              <PropertyName>Target</PropertyName>
                            </ListItem>
                          </ListItems>
                      </ListEntry>
                  </ListEntries>
              </ListControl>
          </View>
          <View>
              <Name>children</Name>
              <ViewSelectedBy>
                  <SelectionSetName>FileSystemTypes</SelectionSetName>
              </ViewSelectedBy>
              <GroupBy>
                  <PropertyName>PSParentPath</PropertyName> 
                  <CustomControlName>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</CustomControlName>  
              </GroupBy>
              <WideControl>
                  <WideEntries>
                      <WideEntry>
                          <WideItem>
                              <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                          </WideItem>
                      </WideEntry>
                      <WideEntry>
                          <EntrySelectedBy>
                              <TypeName>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</TypeName>
                          </EntrySelectedBy>
                          <WideItem>
                              <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                              <FormatString>[{0}]</FormatString>
                          </WideItem>
                      </WideEntry>
                  </WideEntries>
              </WideControl>
          </View>
          <View>
              <Name>FileSecurityTable</Name>
              <ViewSelectedBy>
                  <TypeName>System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity</TypeName>
              </ViewSelectedBy>
              <GroupBy>
                  <PropertyName>PSParentPath</PropertyName> 
                  <CustomControlName>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</CustomControlName>  
              </GroupBy>
              <TableControl>
                  <TableHeaders>
                     <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Path</Label>
                     </TableColumnHeader>
                     <TableColumnHeader />
                     <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Access</Label>
                     </TableColumnHeader>
                  </TableHeaders>
                  <TableRowEntries>
                      <TableRowEntry>
                          <TableColumnItems>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <ScriptBlock>
                                      split-path $_.Path -leaf
                                  </ScriptBlock>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>Owner</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <ScriptBlock>
                                      $_.AccessToString
                                  </ScriptBlock>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                          </TableColumnItems>
                      </TableRowEntry>
                  </TableRowEntries>
              </TableControl>
          </View>
         <View>
              <Name>FileSystemStream</Name>
              <ViewSelectedBy>
                  <TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AlternateStreamData</TypeName>
              </ViewSelectedBy>
              <GroupBy>
                  <PropertyName>Filename</PropertyName> 
              </GroupBy>
              <TableControl>
                  <TableHeaders>
                     <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>20</Width>
                        <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                     </TableColumnHeader>
                      <TableColumnHeader>
                          <Width>10</Width>
                          <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                      </TableColumnHeader>
                  </TableHeaders>
                  <TableRowEntries>
                      <TableRowEntry>
                          <TableColumnItems>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Stream</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                              <TableColumnItem>
                                  <PropertyName>Length</PropertyName>
                              </TableColumnItem>
                          </TableColumnItems>
                      </TableRowEntry>
                  </TableRowEntries>
              </TableControl>
          </View>          
      </ViewDefinitions>
  </Configuration>
  ```

  (It's allmost a direct copy of the original `$PSHOME\FileFormat.format.ps1xml`. I only changed `Length` to `FileSize` a few times)
- load the new format in our powershell session:

  - `Update-FormatData -PrependPath $Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowershell\MyFileFormat.format.ps1xml`
- try the new property

  - `Get-ChildItem`

#### load the changes in `$PROFILE`

- copy these lines to `$PROFILE` to load the changes in every new session

  ```powershell
  # local path to use in this script
  $scriptpath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

  # custom types and formats
  # currently only System.IO.FileInfo is changed
  update-TypeData -PrependPath $scriptpath\MyTypes.ps1xml
  update-FormatData -PrependPath $scriptpath\MyFileFormat.format.ps1xml
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I used jmreicha's solution with an alias in my $profile:

```
function Get-ChildItem-MegaBytes {
  ls $args | Select-Object Name, @{Name="MegaBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}
}

Set-Alias -name megs -val Get-ChildItem-MegaBytes
```

Now I just type: `megs [whatever]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unixy `ls` by installing [a BusyBox port](https://frippery.org/busybox/). [Scoop.sh has the package](https://scoop.sh/#/apps?q=busybox&id=f03e190710e3a7b8e7f491a83ecc2597ff2e25e6).

Then in Powershell, you can define a function to do `ll` in your `$PROFILE`:

```
function ll() {
  ls.exe -lah $args
}
```