# How can I list directories and their sizes in command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I would like to see sizes of subfolders in a folder, similar to linux `du -sh` command. How can I list directories and their sizes in command prompt?

Comment: PS I found this free little software useful as well https://windirstat.info/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `du -sh` - I use [cmder](http://cmder.net/) on Windows and it worked well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the [Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) utility from Sysinternals. Specifically, `du -l 1` should show the size of each subdirectory of the current directory. For more information, run `du` without any parameters.

---

If PowerShell is OK, then try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem |
Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
ForEach-Object {
  $_.Name + ": " + (
    Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
    Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  ).Sum
}
```

The sizes are in bytes. To format them in some larger unit like MB, try the following (condensed to one line):

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name + ": " + "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB) + " MB" }
```

For more information, see [this article at Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx).

If you want more flexible formatting of the sizes (choosing kB/MB/GB/etc based on the actual size), see [this question and its answers](https://superuser.com/q/468782).

---

I don't think it's possible to do what you want from the regular command line and with only a few simple commands. See [this script as an example](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/diskuse_2k.txt) (not going to copy it here because I don't believe that approach is worth pursuing, unless PowerShell isn't available and third-party utilities aren't acceptable).

Comment: Looks good. Will wait a bit to see if there is a native way to do this in command prompt :)

Comment: @giorgio79 See updated answer. It's doable natively in the command prompt, but I'd recommend either Disk Usage, or using PowerShell.

Comment: Great PS one-liner - perfect when you can't deploy any new tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `du` in Linux. But in windows I use `dir /s` to list all folders and subfolders along with file sizes.

Comment: The `/S` switch doesn't show sizes of directories, it simply makes the command recursively go through all subdirectories.

Comment: Look carefully, It shows the size of each folder also. Although its not much human readable.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean - under the file listing of each subdirectory it shows the total size of all files in that directory. Like you say, it's not really easy to read, though, and the sizes aren't shown recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification to [Indrek's answer](https://superuser.com/a/481125/758595). I added the followings:

- made it recursive to go further in subdirectories
- added a size threshold to omit samller directories
- replaced directory names with their relative path from current directory
- sorted results by their path (I found it more convinient rather than sorting them by size, when they are already filtered by size)
- added some formatting to make the results more readable

So, set `$minsizeMB` and `$maxdepth` with the desired values and run the script.

```
$minsizeMB = 100; 
$maxdepth = 5; 
Get-ChildItem -depth $maxdepth -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Select-Object FullName | 
    Sort-Object FullName |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $directory = Get-Item $_.FullName;
        $path = Resolve-Path -Relative $directory.FullName ; 
        $size = ((Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB) ; 
        if ($size -ge $minsizeMB) { "{0,-90}: {1:N2} MB" -f ($path, $size) } 
    }
```