# List directories with size recursively?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Continuing [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/481125/23133) from [How can I list directories and their sizes in command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/481117/how-can-i-list-directories-and-their-sizes-in-command-prompt)

How to list directories recursively with size using PowerShell?

Comment: What are you trying to exactly? List and Sort by size and have re-list them every 30 seconds if the size changes? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i just want to list directory name along with size recursively. something similar to unix command `du -h`

Comment: this command prints overall usage of current directory- `powershell -noprofile -command "ls -r|measure -s Length"` but i want to print name with size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to list directories recursively with size using PowerShell?

If it's really just a recursive list you need including the file size for each file then give [ForFiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) a shot using the syntax below which happens to work with [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) as well as command line, and it has a very similar output to the Unix `du -h` command as you indicate you need in a comment.

### Universal PowerShell and Command Line Method

<sub>*Output is similar to Unix `du -h` but you could format further if needed.*</sub>

```
FORFILES /S /M * /C "CMD /C ECHO @FSIZE          @PATH"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**ForFiles**](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

Comment: thank you so much. it list files and directories both, i found what i was looking for!

Comment: How to use this solution for UNC paths?

Comment: @kurp Unfortunately forfiles doesn't support UNC paths that I know of but as a workaround you can first run `PUSHD "\\servername\sharename"` then run `FORFILES /S /M * /C "CMD /C ECHO @FSIZE          @PATH"`, and when it's done or on the next line run `POPD` and this will essentniallys change to the UNC path and run the command for you and create an arbitrary network mapping and use a drive letter for you then unmap it when done with `popd`