# Powershell - How do I convert the length property to human readable?

Tags: powershell

Im sure there are other ways to do this, but im trying to learn and trying to see how I can convert this length output to GB format

```
dir $env:USERPROFILE -Recurse -File | sort-object -property length | select -last 10
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Does [Show human-readable file sizes in the default PowerShell ls command](https://superuser.com/questions/468782/show-human-readable-file-sizes-in-the-default-powershell-ls-command) help?

Comment: I tried that but was more looking for the below, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy `-h` like in Linux. You could do it like this:

```
select *,@{n='Length (GB)';e={$_.Length / 1GB}} -exclude length -last 10
```

Basically you select every property (`*`) add a [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) to the output `@{n='Length (GB)';e={$_.Length / 1GB}}` and exclude the normal length (optional)

Comment: Thanks SimonS, that did it. I will now try and wrap my head around how exactly that works!

Comment: Im trying to see if there is a way to use math::[round] or something to only have 2 decimal places? or may {0:F2}?

Comment: @Matt yes, like this `e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1GB)}}`, -f is the format operator