# How to set WSL default path to ~ (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

Running the command `ubuntu` in Windows Terminal puts the directory as linux default, but running `wsl` causes it to mount  at `/mnt/%USERPROFILE%`. I know I can just run `ubuntu`, but I'm used to using `wsl` instead. I checked my Windows Terminal config and that is fine (no defined directory, using dropdown menu sets as `~`). I'm sorry if this may sound confusing as I am relatively new to wsl. The terminal did not behave like this until recently. Setting `StartingDirectory` or `CommandLine` does not work. This problem may be related more to WSL than Ubuntu

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Open Windows Terminal
2. Enter command `wsl`

#### Expected Behaviour

Open Ubuntu WSL in `~`

#### Actual Behaviour

Opens Ubuntu WSL in `/mnt/c/users/<username>`

Comment: running WSL starts WSL with the current directory set to the directory you are currently in when you launched WSL - which is completely expected and useful

Comment: If you want to force it, you should be able to put that  in your .bashrc but as @JaromandaX points out.. that is sort of counterproductive.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I used to have `cd ~` in `.profile` not `.bashrc` until I realised the usefulness of not doing that :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it was not always like that until a couple of months ago. When I first used it, it would start in the distro's home directory and have nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: perhaps an update changed the behaviour, still, it makes perfect sense to work how it does work

Comment: Why exactly is it useful? What are you doing in the windows drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's no way to change the *default* directory that is entered when you run `wsl.exe` (for good reason, see below), the best workaround is to to simply run `wsl ~`, which will start in the default user's home directory.  For Windows Terminal, you can set the profile's "Command Line" setting to `wsl ~`, which will override the "Starting Directory".

*More Explanation:*

When *any* executable starts under Windows (or Linux), it inherits the "current working directory" from the application that started it.  It can (and often does) set a new working directory during the startup.

The `wsl.exe` and `ubuntu.exe` commands differ a bit in their design:

- `wsl.exe` is designed to install, modify, or launch WSL itself
- `ubuntu.exe` is designed to install, modify, or launch the Ubuntu distribution.  Like most "pre-packaged" WSL distributions, `ubuntu.exe` is based on the [WSL distro launcher reference implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/tree/master/DistroLauncher) that Microsoft provides.  [Here](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL) is the forked version for the Ubuntu installer/launcher.

You can examine the source code of the distro-launcher and find the `WslApiLoader::WslLaunchInteractive` that has a `useCurrentWorkingDirectory` boolean argument.  This is passed to the equivalent function in the (closed-source) `wslapi.dll`.  That API, in turns, launches Ubuntu and (through its `init` function):

- Determines the default user
- Looks up their shell
- Starts the shell in the specified directory (`~` if the above parameter is `false`, and the parent process working directory otherwise)
- (and much more)

`ubuntu.exe` is the "easy button" version of launching Ubuntu.  It *doesn't* provide much additional control to the user.

`wsl.exe`, on the other hand, has quite a few command-line arguments that allow you to control exactly what is launched and how, including:

- The directory in which to start, either through `wsl ~` (shortcut for launching in the home directory) or `wsl --cd <directory>`
- The ability to launch as a different user (`wsl -u <username>`)
- The ability to skip launching the default shell and run a command in its place (`wsl -e <command>`)
- And more

Here's a simple example of why you should *want* the `wsl.exe` command to default to the current working directory.  From PowerShell:

```
wsl ls -lh
```

This will (as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1664131/1210833)) show you *human readable* file sizes in the directory listing, something that isn't easy to do in PowerShell otherwise.

If `wsl.exe` defaulted to the home directory, the equivalent command would give you a listing of files in *that* directory, rather than the current PowerShell directory.

Being able to use Linux commands through `wsl` directly in PowerShell can be quite flexible and powerful.

It's also for similar reason that I recommend against modifying `~/.bashrc` to change your directory.

---

Alternative:

While `wsl ~` is pretty short as it is (5 characters, still 1 less than `ubuntu`), you could also "alias" it to something like `wslh` (or even something shorter) in PowerShell.  However, since PowerShell aliases don't support arguments, you would need to add a function to your `profile.ps1`.  Something like:

```
function wslh {
    wsl ~ @args
}
```

This will allow you to use `wslh` to start in the home directory.  You can still use arguments like `wslh -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 -e ls` (et. al.) as well.

Comment: It seems I'll have to get used to `wsl ~` for now.

Comment: @vvxrtues Right.  On the bright side, from Windows Terminal it's just a one-time change.  And when starting it from PowerShell, you get used to it real fast.  It's still shorter than `ubuntu` ;-).  You could even use `Set-Alias` in PowerShell if you wanted to alias it to something like `wslh`.

Comment: I forgot about `Set-Alias`, that would make things even more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how can I set up the Alias?

Comment: @vvxrtues No worries!  And my bad - I forgot that PowerShell aliases don't support arguments  Use a function instead -- I've added an example to my answer at the end.  Thanks!

Comment: Also make sure to put the ~ straight after wsl if you have any other params (like -d blahblah)